changing emulator screen into 80 by 80
I am currently doing an pixel art in emulator, I wanted to ask if anybody knows how to change the screen size of the emu into 80x80. I have tried dragging it but it's either the design will deform, or just nothing. I have tried to change the background color and drag the screen when run, but it is just until 24 column that is white, the rest are black.

There is no universal – everyone adheres to this procedure – method. You need to specify the processor, i. e. the operating system, the (emulated) terminal, the terminal emulator, the programming language, the libraries you use, all such details. In the end I recommend instead of changing anything just start a new terminal emulator where you have full control about all its options.
